# 504 Gateway Time-out when pdf with image is generated in prestashop 1.6.1.3 from front office and back office

Tags: pdf, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

We are getting 504 Gateway Time-out when pdf with image is generated in prestashop 1.6.1.3

In the .tpl file we have the path of the image  as shown below :

```
<td width="50%" valign="top"><table width="100%" style="padding:10px;" id="leftTable"><tr><td>
{if $product_id==2}
<img src="http://mywebsite.ae/img/images1.jpg" style="width:200px; height:81px;" />
{else}
<img src="http://mywebsite.ae/img/images2.jpg" style="width:200px; height:86px;" />
{/if}
```

We are using the tcpdf library (even updated the latest tcpdf library  -)
[image]

Comment: there might be a permission issue with the image you are trying to use..

Comment: Are you sure it is connected to image path ? Have you tried without that condition ? What file you are editing and is `$product_id` defined correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to increase server time out value?? Maby changing image options to a less definition format?? Prestashop advices that include images in PDF render could make PDF generation slower.

Regards